# Python ncurses script error on boot

Tags: python, cron, ncurses

I have this python script working fine when I run it in shell :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import shlex, subprocess
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(1)

stdscr.addstr(0,10,"Hit 'q' to quit")
stdscr.refresh()

cmd = "antimicro --profile /home/pi/dragon.joystick.amgp --daemon --hidden"
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(4, gpio.OUT)
key = ''
while(key != ord('q')):
 key = stdscr.getch()
 stdscr.addch(20,25,key)
 stdscr.refresh()
 if (key == ord('a')):
  gpio.output(4, not gpio.input(4))
 print key
```

Now, I want this script to run on boot, I set it up with `crontab`, but on boot the script won't run, and give me this log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
stdscr = curses.initscr()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/curses/__init__.py", line 33, in initscr
fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
_curses.error setupterm could not find terminal
```

After some research I tried to setup `TERMINFO` to `/etc/terminfo`, but it didn't help. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm on Raspbian (os for raspberry), and I'm using xterm, so `echo $TERM` outputs `xterm`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the cron part earlier... Do you want this to run from inside X with an `xterm`? Or just in the basic non-graphical Linux console?

Comment: The environment variable `TERM` is set to `xterm` when you run this during boot or when you run it manually?

Comment: @EtanReisner When I run it manually, I don't know its value on boot.

Comment: You should probably check that. Print it from the python script.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It doesn't really matter for the final user application, as long as the script accepts key pressed (the user has no screen, just a push button)

Comment: @EtanReisner I'll try that and come back

Comment: @EtanReisner The problem is that the application isn't run in a terminal *at all* since it's run from cron. So TERM will always be empty here. He'll need to use `xterm -e 'python myscript.py'` or some such, but I'm not sure if that works from cron... You probably want to use `~/.xsession` or whatever startup file your window manager/display manager uses...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It isn't run in an X terminal. It is run under some conditions. Presumably `dumb` or similar. And quite likely `TERM` is not set (that's what I was trying to have the OP notice). Setting it to something (like `dumb` or `linux`) might be enough for what the OP wants to do. Though... looking at the script again possibly not since that seems to actually want to get user input.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not sure if you can run ncurses apps with `dumb` terminal? well, it's perhaps *possible*, but it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me (why use ncurses if you don't want graphical stuff?)

Comment: How are you expecting to get user input during the boot process? Where are you intending for this output to be seen and when are you expecting the input to be given?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm using ncurses just to get the key pressed. I can't use `msvcrt` so using ncurses is the easiest way I found to do this in python.
So just to clarify, here's what I'm trying to do : I have a push button connected to my raspberry (recognized as a joystick), so I set up this button to act like an 'a' keyboard entry (in my antimicro conf file), so when the user push the button the raspberry switch the gpio4 input. The script works fine, now I need it to run when the raspberry boot so I don't have to run it myself everytime. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: I just tried to add a `sleep 60` before the script exec in the cron file, now I have no logs but it still doesn't work

Comment: A cron job has no input attached. It cannot get input from the user like this. You cannot do this this way. You need the script to get its input *independently* from a running shell/terminal.

Comment: Ok thank's, i'll figure another way